# Python range alternative

Tags: python, loops, syntax, numbers

```
for i in range(10):

for i in 0 .. 9:
```

How do I 'overload'?  '..' .

I find the `range()` object not concise or easy to read. The pascal notation/syntax (range (inclusive .. inclusive) http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Pascal.html ) just so much easier to read.

I saw in the pathlib module https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html that it overloads(?) the / character.

Comment: `..` is not a valid python operator, so you cannot overload it.

Comment: The best you could do is wrap the first number in a wrapper class, then have the class overload a operator to accept an end number, and have that return a range. Don't do that though. Just get used to `range` since that's what all code uses.

Answer (score 0):

While `Python` does not have the `..` operator, you could define an infix operator like so:

```
class Infix:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __rlshift__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __rshift__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __call__(self, value1, value2):
        return self.function(value1, value2)
```

Now, choose a meaningful name like `until` and you're done:

```
until = Infix(lambda x,y: range(x,y +1))
print(2 |until| 4)
# [2, 3, 4]
```

Or

```
for i in (2 |until| 4):
    print(i)
```

Unfortunalety not my idea, see [**this brilliant post for the original idea**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/).

Comment: I’d probably go with something simpler like `def irange(a, b): return range(a, b + 1)`. While interesting, this seems to go overboard and makes for very unpythonic code.

Comment: @deceze: Completely agree. Kinda lispy though (without the parentheses, that is).

Comment: Could you use |..|   ? So, for i in 0 |..| 9:   ? .. = Infix(lambda x,y: range(x,y +1))

Comment: (You (can (always (add those) back (in (anyway))))))))))).

Comment: @deceze: I go and get a t-shirt with it :)

Comment: @JoePythonKing: No, you can't as `Python` does not allow it for variable names.

Comment: for i in (2 |To| 4):   -  I hate those bars.

Comment: @JoePythonKing: But that's as far as it will get, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JoePythonKing it might be possible using some obscure unicode character that looks like a dot.